# Motioneye on Raspbian - Run a Command python script failing

Tags: python, motion

So on my Raspberry Pi with Motioneye (not OS) installed and I'm trying to get the Pushover Notification to work. The problem is on Raspbian I'm not sure where to put the python script. I've put it in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin` but no matter where I place the script it never activates.

the pushover.py looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#################################################################################
# Created by Wesley Archer (aka. Raspberry Coulis) to enable push notifications #
# via Pushover.net in MotionEyeOS. See Pushover's API FAQ for more detailed use #
# Also featured on Pi-Supply.com's Maker Zone.                                  #
#                                                                               #
# Follow me:    @RaspberryCoulis                                                #
# Visit me:     raspberrycoulis.co.uk                                           #
# Email me:     wesley@raspberrycoulis.co.uk                                    #
# Like me:  facebook.com/raspberrycoulis                                    #
#################################################################################

import httplib, urllib

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
  urllib.urlencode({
    "token": "my api token"   # Insert app token here
    "user": "My user token",       # Insert user token here
    "html": "1",                                # 1 for HTML, 0 to disable
    "title": "Motion Detected!",                # Title of the message
    "message": "<b>Front Door</b> camera!",     # Content of the message
    "url": "http://IP.ADD.RE.SS",               # Link to be included in message
    "url_title": "View live stream",            # Text for the link
    "sound": "siren",                           # Define the sound played
  }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
conn.getresponse()
```

When I try to execute the python script I get:

```
  File "./pushover.py", line 20
    "user": "My token",       # Insert user token here
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Simply insert user token there. Do you how can you get it?

Comment: I did, when I copy and pasted it to the question I made sure to replace the token with just api token or user token. I signed into PUshover and grab the tokens from there

Comment: I think you must add `,` at the end of line 19. Like `"token": "my api token",`.

Comment: i agree with @M.Rostami, the coding error is on the previous line

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for the agreement. I just added it as an answer.

Comment: @M.Rostami, that type of a mistake is the exact reason why i like to put the separating commas before the parameter instead of after the parameter

Comment: @jsotola Yes, would be more clear to arrange `,`s.

Comment: @M.Rostami, i also do that in `if` statements with complex boolean expessions ... i put each ecpression on a separate line and place the `&&` and `||` at the begining of lines

Answer (score 2):

You must add `,` at the end of line 19. Like `"token": "my api token",`. So your `pushover.py` gonna be like it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib, urllib

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
  urllib.urlencode({
    "token": "my api token",
    "user": "My user token",
    "html": "1",
    "title": "Motion Detected!",
    "message": "<b>Front Door</b> camera!",
    "url": "http://IP.ADD.RE.SS",
    "url_title": "View live stream",
    "sound": "siren",
  }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
conn.getresponse()
```